# Is it possible to open a MP3 file on Windows 10 without showing the groove window

Tags: windows, mp3

I am working on a program and one part of the program requires an mp3 file to play. However, I do not want it to open the Groove Music or VLC window, which opens by default. It would be a VBS script that opens the music file, so is there a way to add a few elements into the code so it won't open the user's default media player?

Additional Details

OS: Windows 10

Program is coded in Visual Basic

I will happily provide any more details that are needed

Comment: The solution is to use WMP control [vbscript - VBS Play Sound With no Dialogue - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367004/vbs-play-sound-with-no-dialogue) - Works on Windows 10 as well.

Comment: You can play directly in your program see [here](https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/visual-basic/9267/how-create-music-player-visual-basic.html)